# Visual Studio Team Services Checking in files to Default Collection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio Team Services and for some reason my changesets are being checked into the "Default Collection"...which contains the project this solution is a part of.

How do I make sure changesets are being associated with the actual project and not at the "level" above that?

Comment: That's not possible. Check-ins are always associated with a TeamProject. Can you show me a screenshot? Also, check your workspace mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment its not possible to check-in files at the Collection level. You will get following error on doing that. Check your workspace mapping.

[image]

Comment: Awesome Adarsh...the problem was a multitude of misaligned workspace mappings.  I deleted them all and started adding them back in exactly where I wanted them and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!